# What can I substitute the cocoa powder with for this mille crepe recipe?

Tags: baking, cake, ratio, crepe

I'm following [this recipe](https://tasty.co/recipe/mille-crepe-cake#tips) of a mille crepe, where they do the crepes with cocoa powder.

I want to try to make the crepes without cocoa, what should I do?

The current recipe is

CREPE

- 6 tablespoons butter
- 3 cups milk(675 mL)
- 6 eggs
- 1 1/2 cups flour(210 g)
- 2/3 cup cocoa powder(80 g)
- 7 tablespoons sugar
- 4 cups whipped cream(1 L)

I see so many different informations online, I don't know what to do. I understand cocoa powder is more dry and more acidic than flour, so it cannot be a 1:1 ratio, so what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Can't you just find a recipe that doesn't have cocoa powder in it?  There's [one here](https://patisseriewong.com/mille-crepes#:~:text=Mille%20Cr%C3%AApes%20A%20classic%20French%20g%C3%A2teau%2C%20consists%20of,the%20layers%20and%20better%20mouth%20feel%20as%20well.)

Comment: Thank you, all the recipes I found either didn't put sugar in their crepes, didn't put butter, or didn't put eggs. The one you linked looks good :)

Comment: Does this help you: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/108976/29838 This may be somewhat a duplicate question.